# 403 Forbidden en ruta laravel 8

Tags: laravel

Tengo problemas para acceder a la ruta `housekeeping` me da un error `403 Forbidden`

Mis rutas:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {

    Route::prefix('dashboard')->group(function () {

        Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

    });
});

//Housekeeping

Route::prefix('housekeeping')->group(function () {

    Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\HousekeepingController::class, 'index'])->name('housekeeping');

});
```

Mi controlador:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HousekeepingController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('housekeeping.welcome');
    }
}
```

Mi directorio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si cambio le nombre del prefijo `housekeeping` por `housekeeper`, `hola` o cualquier otro... funciona

Comment: ¿Tienes algún subdirectorio `housekeeping`dentro de `public/`?

Comment: Sí, etaba pensando que eso podría estar afectando y cambié el nombre del subdirectorio dentro de resources, pero en public no.

Comment: Resuelto. muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con la pista de que no puedes acceder a `/housekeeping` mientras otras rutas funcionan bien (En tus palabras: "Si cambio le nombre del prefijo `housekeeping` por `housekeeper`, `hola` o cualquier otro... funciona"), significa que tus rutas Laravel y el archivo `.htaccess` están funcionando.

Entonces, el problema probablemente se deba a que `.htaccess` omite la reescritura de URL solo para la URL `/housekeeping`, eso relacionado con estas tres líneas en `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Las dos primeras líneas le dicen a Apache (o al server que uses) que no reescriba la URL en el `index.php` de Laravel si la URL solicitada apunta a un archivo o carpeta existente.
El hecho de que muestre `403 Forbidden` se debe probablemente a que el servidor está intentando acceder al directorio `housekeeping/` , pero no tiene permitido hacerlo.

Entonces, la solución es asegurarse de no tener un subdirectorio en `tu-proyecto/public/` que coincida con la primer parte de la uri de una de tus rutas. O al revés, que ninguna de las uris tus rutas, coincida con un subdirectorio en `tu-proyecto/public/`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, excelente!